# How to correct expand commands,to insert it in actualtext?

Tags: luatex, expl3

I try to redefine equation environment,to insert actualtext of formula. But if i insert the space after equation,i get `\test{1}{0}`. When i not insert space after setting of actualtext of equation,i get as expected `1+0=1-0`.

1. How to do correct expandion of commands even if after setting of
   actual text i have space.
2. How do this expandion,using expl3 functions?

Thanks everybody for any help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tagpdf,unicode-math}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure,uncompress,activate-all,interwordspace=true}
\protected\def\DoTaggedEquation#1{
\tagstructbegin{tag=P,actualtext-o=\detokenize\expandafter{#1}}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
#1
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{equation}{
\incr@eqnum
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredfalse \global\@eqnswtrue
 \mathdisplay{equation}%
  \collect@body\DoTaggedEquation\c_space_tl}{
  \endmathdisplay{equation}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\test}[2]{#1+#2=#1-#2}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\tagstructbegin{tag={Document}}
\begin{equation}\test{1}{0}\end{equation}
\tagstructend
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably need `\detokenize\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}`

Comment: Maybe it's better to use ``\detokenize\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0#1}``.  That will stop at the first unexpandable token instead of blowing up your document.

Comment: @Henri Menke Thank you very much for your help and now it works as i want,but i not understand,why it wasn't work correct without \expanded command? Also i want to know,how correct do the same using expl3 features? Thank you very much for your help again.

Comment: In expl3 you'd do `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_to_str:n { e }` and then use `\tl_to_str:e { #1 }` instead of `\detokenize\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}`.

Comment: It wasn't working without `\expanded` because with the leading space it would expand to `\detokenize\expandafter{ \test{1}{0}}` where `\expandafter` would try to expand the space instead of `\test`.

Comment: @Henri Menke Thank you very much. It very interesting for me,why with expl3 it better use tl_to_str? Because i considered,that exp_args function it a best variant with expl3.

Comment: @Henri Menke I rewrite my command as:
\newcommand{\test}[2]{#1*#2=\frac{#1}{#2}}
But for 1 and 1 i have actualtext as:
1*1=\protect {\Ustack {\group_begin: 1\group_end: \@@over 1}}
instead of
1*2=\frac{1}{2}
Why this not works for frac command and how to do,to expanding works for all commands? Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: `\frac` is not a robust macro, so it will expand to its definition inside `\expanded`.  You have to write `\noexpand\frac` to prevent that.  Alternatively you can expand up to the first unexpandable token by using `f` type expansion, i.e. `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_to_str:n { f }` and then use `\tl_to_str:f { #1 }` which is essentially `\detokenize\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0#1}`.